# How does the dependency injection with the CommunityToolkit.MVVM work?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I would like to improve the navigation between my view in a WPF application, and I have seen that one way is to use dependency injection and services that resolve the dependencies.

For that, I an reading the documentation of CommunityToolkit.MVVM but I am not sure how it works.

This is the link: [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/ioc)

First, it configures the services:

```
private static IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    services.AddSingleton<IFilesService, FilesService>();
    services.AddSingleton<IConsoleService, ConsoleService>();
    services.AddSingleton<IFileLogger, FileLogger>();

    return services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

And later I can retrieve an implementation of a service:

```
IFileLogger fileLogger = App.Current.Services.GetService<IFileLogger>();
```

If I don't understand wrong, when I retrieve a `fileLogger`, it will create the file logger that is registered in the configuration method. In this case the `FileLogger` implementation.

Also, this `FileLogger` has two parameters, that are registered too, `IFileService` and `IConsoleService`.

For example in the case of the `IFileService`, it is used the implementation `FileService`. But what happens if I have many implementations of `IFileService`? For example, one for local file service, another for remote service and so on. How could I choose which implementation to use if in the configuration method it is set that it will always use the `FileService`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in DI container is not very friendly for those cases. You have some choices though:

1.First register the implementations with the interface:

```
services.AddSingleton<IFileService, LocalFileService>();
services.AddSingleton<IFileService, RemoteFileService>();
```

Then you can simply resolve them by injecting the IServiceProvider like:

```
IServiceProvider.GetServices<IFileService>().First(x => x is RemoteFileService);
```

However, injecting the IServiceProvider is considered an anti-pattern called service locator.

2.Register and resolve them as concrete types

```
services.AddSingleton<LocalFileService();
services.AddSingleton<RemoteFileService();
```

and then simply inject these types in any constructor and they will get resolved by the container.
This solution is violating the SOLID principles, because then your classes will not depend on abstractions, they will depend on concrete types.

3.Use factory pattern

```
public class FileServiceFactory : IFileServiceFactory
{
    public IFileService GetFileService(string type)
    {
        if (type == "local")
        {
            return new LocalFileService();
        }
        
        return new RemoteFileService();
    }
}
```

Then register the factory itself with the DI container

```
services.AddSingleton<IFileServiceFactory, FileServiceFactory>();
```

and then inject the factory in your constructors.
Then you can get your services by calling

```
IFileServiceFactory.GetFileService("remote");
```

This factory pattern can then be further optimized to use DI instead of instatiating these services using the `new` keyword, and other techniques which is a broad topic and is step by step explained in this video by Tim Corey https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PXAfSfvRKY. You can also use `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance();` if you want to pass primitive parameters to the constructor of the services which the DI doesn't know how to resolve.